# What is the difference between uptime and uptime_since_flush_status?

Tags: mysql, global-state

I have been reading on mysql global status variables and I see two values:

- uptime
- uptime_since_flush_status

What does `uptime_since_flush_status` mean?

Answer (score 5):

`Uptime` is the the number of seconds that the server has been up.

`Uptime_since_flush_status` is the number of seconds since the most recent `FLUSH STATUS` statement.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Uptime.

Comment: Hi Michale, thanks for the quick reply. What does it mean by this FLUSH STATUS...?

Comment: Best explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html. About half way down the page is the section you're looking for.

Comment: Hi michale, thanks for the reply. What is this FLUSH STATUS does mean actually..?